# UICollectionViewController with dynamic header (like Reddit App)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am looking for a way to implement a header view that automatically hides once you start scrolling down and immediately shows itself once the user starts scrolling up.
Usually, I always post some code, but now I am a little bit lost on how to implement such behaviour.

My view layout:

- `UICollectionViewController` with paging enabled for horizontal
  scrolling (has two items)
- The `UICollectionViewCell` fills the entire vertical space. Each UICollectionViewCell hosts a UITableView for vertical scrolling. I assume that I have to use the UITableView vertical scrolling position to adjust the frame of the menu bar.

Video: https://imgur.com/a/Rdu3wko

What would be the best way to implement such a behaviour?

Comment: I think it's UITableview not a collection view

Comment: I think it is a UICollectionView with three items and paging enabled. I don't know how the header view could be created otherwise.

Comment: Maybe this one helps you https://github.com/cillyfly/MXScroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `UICollectionView`, just grab the delegate, see which direction the user is scrolling, and hide/show the header as needed. Here's an example to get you started:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Variable to save the last scroll offset.
    private var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0

    private lazy var header: UIView = {
        let header = UIView()
        header.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        header.backgroundColor = .red
        header.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.width).isActive = true
        header.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0).isActive = true
        return header
    }()

    private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 2000.0)
        // Setting bounces to false - otherwise the header will disappear when we go past the top and are sprung back.
        collectionView.bounces = false
        return collectionView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 2000.0)

        // Make sure you either add the header subview last, or call self.view.bringSubviewToFront(header)
        self.view.addSubview(header)
        // Constrain the header so it's just sitting on top of the view. To make it visible, we'll use a transform.
        header.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        header.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        // Header starts visible.
        header.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.header.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: header.frame.height)
    }

    func revealHeader() {
        // Set the duration below to how quickly you want header to appear/disappear.
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.header.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: self.header.frame.height)
        }

    }

    func hideHeader() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.header.transform = .identity
        }
    }

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if (lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            // Scrolled up: reveal header.
            revealHeader()
        }
        else if (lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            // Scrolled down: reveal header.
            hideHeader()
        }

        lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }

}
```

---

**EDIT:** Noticed the functionality of the Reddit header is a bit different. If you want the thing to scroll dynamically (i.e. by the amount you have scrolled down by as opposed to appear all at once) replace that delegate function with this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        // Scrolled up: reveal header.
        let difference = lastContentOffset - scrollView.contentOffset.y
        if header.transform.ty < (header.frame.height - difference) {
            // Header hasn't been fully revealed yet, bring it down by the amount we've scrolled up.
            self.header.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: header.transform.ty + difference)
        } else {
                self.header.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: header.frame.height)
        }
    }
        else if (lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            // Scrolled down: reveal header.
            let difference = scrollView.contentOffset.y - lastContentOffset
            if header.transform.ty > difference {
                self.header.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: header.transform.ty - difference)
            } else {
                self.header.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            }
        }

        lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement this solution into my app.

Comment: No problem! Added an alternative above should you need it.

Comment: Hello, I have one more question: Now the header is shown and scrolls really smoothly, it looks really nice, thank you again. However, The view covers the first cell. How can I change the behavior so the cell starts just underneath the Header Menu? I saw the contentInset property, but changing the contentInset programatically made the UIScrollView "jumpy". Is there a better solution?

Comment: Replace the `header.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true` line with `header.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true`. Then remove this line: `collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true` and add this after you add header as a subview: `collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

Comment: Because I no longer use a UIViewConroller (but a UICollectionViewController instead), I had to tweak things a little bit, but your code helped me tremendously, so thank you very much, it now finally works and looks very good too.

Answer (score -1):

This functionality is possible in `UITableView`  set parallax header otherwise `UIScrollView` parallax animation.

Comment: Hello, do you have an example? Can you maybe send me a link?

Comment: Check this [https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/how-to-create-a-stretchable-tableviewheader-in-ios-ee9ed049aba3]

[https://github.com/romansorochak/ParallaxHeader]

[https://github.com/maxep/MXParallaxHeader]

You may refer [https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=parallax]

also you search on [https://cocoapods.org]  and many more .

Comment: I think what makes this far more complicated is the fact that I have a UICollectionView with horizontal scrolling. Your examples specifically only use one single UITableView.

Comment: If you want to use `UICollectionView` the set  `UIScrollView` for set Parallax animation.

Comment: @J.Doe all links working perfectly  when you open link check ULRLink open with **]**  so please remove it worked, And now i can't edit my answer so i could not update my answer.